Any tips as to how to use github's repositories in your python code?
I am trying to utilize YOLOv8's software seen on their github, but I don't know how to implant it in jupyter labs.
I am trying to see what lines of code I should implement in python 3.x to get this to work. Would this require a pip install of some sort? How can I make my code connect with the internet in this way?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please edit your title to specifically describe your issue. If you read the text you are asking about a very particular library and that should be reflected in the title. Please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'.

To use YOLOv8 in Jupyter Lab, you will need to install the necessary libraries, including the YOLOv8 package, and then run the code to perform object detection.
Install YOLOv8 and dependencies:
!pip install ultralytics
!pip install opencv-python-headless

Load YOLOv8 model and perform detection:
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load YOLOv8 model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')  # You can choose a different model size such as yolov8s.pt, yolov8m.pt, etc.

# Load an image
img_path = 'path/to/your/image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Run inference
results = model(img)

# Display results
results.show()

Download an image for testing:
import requests

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devicons/devicon/master/icons/typescript/typescript-original.svg'
img_path = 'downloaded_image.svg'

response = requests.get(url)
with open(img_path, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)

# Now you can use this image with YOLOv8
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
results = model(img)
results.show()

Display the results in Jupyter Lab:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Convert the image from BGR to RGB
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(results.ims[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Display the image with detections
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


Please don't recommend using install commands in conjunction with exclamation points in modern Jupyter when running installs from inside an active Jupyter notebook file. In 2019, the magic install commands were added to ensure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. See more about the modern %pip install command here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.
